# Problem with converting to 'datetime' type: "hour must be in 0..23"

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

These are some sample rows from my csv file :

```
10/10/1949 20:30,san marcos,tx,us,cylinder,2700,45 minutes,"This event took place in early fall around 1949-50. It occurred after a Boy Scout meeting in the Baptist Church. The Baptist Church sit",4/27/2004,29.8830556,-97.9411111
10/10/1949 21:00,lackland afb,tx,,light,7200,1-2 hrs,"1949 Lackland AFB&#44 TX.  Lights racing across the sky &amp; making 90 degree turns on a dime.",12/16/2005,29.38421,-98.581082
10/10/1955 17:00,chester (uk/england),,gb,circle,20,20 seconds,"Green/Orange circular disc over Chester&#44 England",1/21/2008,53.2,-2.916667
10/10/1956 21:00,edna,tx,us,circle,20,1/2 hour,"My older brother and twin sister were leaving the only Edna theater at about 9 PM&#44...we had our bikes and I took a different route home",1/17/2004,28.9783333,-96.6458333
```

The full csv file is [here](https://github.com/planetsig/ufo-reports/blob/master/csv-data/ufo-scrubbed-geocoded-time-standardized.csv).

I load it into a dataframe. In column name `'datetime'`, I have format `'object'`.  I tried to convert type `'object'` into type `'datetime'` like this :

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)
```

As the result I get this error :

```
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

Any help will be apreciated!

Comment: You have `694` entries in your dataframe where timestamp have value `24` for the hour. which is not a valid convention. You have to preprocess the dataset and convert those timestamps accoringly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously problem is `24:00`, solution is [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), `date`s convert by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and `time` by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and sum together:

```
print (df)
           datetime
0  10/10/1949 20:30
1  10/10/1949 21:00
2  10/10/1955 17:00
3  10/10/1956 24:00

df[['date','time']] = df['datetime'].str.split(expand=True)
df['datetime'] = (pd.to_datetime(df.pop('date'), format='%d/%m/%Y') + 
                  pd.to_timedelta(df.pop('time') + ':00'))
print (df)
             datetime
0 1949-10-10 20:30:00
1 1949-10-10 21:00:00
2 1955-10-10 17:00:00
3 1956-10-11 00:00:00
```

Comment: df.datetime = df.datetime.str.replace('24:','00:')

Comment: @WojciechMoszczyński - So you dont need add one day if `24:00` ?

Comment: I think so, 24:01 = 00:01

Comment: @WojciechMoszczyński - Yes, reason for I dont use `replace` is added one day if `24:00` or `24:01` or more.

Comment: @WojciechMoszczyński - But if dont need it, `df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime.str.replace('24:','00:'))` working nice.

Comment: I have to check it - it is very valuable suggestion from you :-). Probably you have right.

Comment: It is my only experience :) Nice day!

Comment: Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: This is a solid, clean solution. Thank you!