# pandas cannot parse some datetime2(3) dates

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I'd like to select data from a MS SQL Server (Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)) and load it into a pandas data frame. This works fine, most of the time, but for some date values, pandas raises errors - and I can't get my head around the reason for it.

Here's what I'm doing:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pymssql

con = pymssql.connect(<server>, <user>, <password>, <database>)
sql = "select CreateDateTime, TagValue from dbo.Test where TagId = 7"
df = pd.read_sql(sql, con)
```

The table i'm using:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [TagId] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CreateDateTime] [datetime2](3) NULL,
    [TagValue] [real] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO dbo.Test
SELECT 7, '2019-03-07 23:59:59.999', -1.2
```

The error I'm getting:

```py
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

I also tried using `df = pd.read_sql(sql, con, parse_dates={'CreateDateTime': {'format': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'} })` but, again, with no luck.

Can someone help me and point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some date where the time is 24:00?

Comment: No, the the table has only the one entry shown above.

Comment: Can you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135059/problem-with-converting-to-datetime-type-hour-must-be-in-0-23

Comment: Problem is, I can't load the data, so I can't do any processing on it. Pandas apparanetly assumes the column "CreateDateTime" is a date, which is correct, but for some reason cannot parse it...

Comment: pymssql has some precision issues around the `datetime2` data type. Ref: [The DATATIME2 precision problems. #608](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/608) and [Improve TIME/DATETIME2 precision and handle DATETIMEOFFSET #665](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/pull/665).